# Video Cannot Be Play, ERROR/MediaPlayerService(128)

Tags: java, android, video, android-videoview

Im developing android apps to play video on fragment.
the code like below :

```
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoPath));                              
videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(rootView.getContext())); 
videoView.requestFocus();                                                 
videoView.start();
```

But when run in devide, the error :

```
ERROR/MediaPlayerService(128): Request requires android.permission.INTERNET
```

i already add internet permission in my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

how to solve this?

manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.APPS"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"/>
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon_APPS">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <activity android:name= ".splash_APPS"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="APPS" android:label="@string/app_name"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: if you are using eclipse, try cleaning the whole project from Project menu, and try again after rebuilding.

Comment: Check out this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html) for more info

Comment: Have you try to run in your real device??

Comment: @yogx im using intelliJ

Comment: @PiyushGupta yups. already run in device. this happen.

Comment: please provide your manifest file...

Comment: @yogx i already add into my question. please refer.

Comment: whole manifest file, not a line from it..

Comment: @yogx that is  a whole manifest file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your have used **uses-permission** tag is inside the application tag. It is a direct sub tag of manifest tab. Refer [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)

Try this...

```
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon_APPS">
        <activity android:name= ".splash_APPS"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="APPS" android:label="@string/app_name"/>
    </application> </manifest>
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: so where to put the uses-permission?

Comment: ok. i already fixed it, but another error appear. nvm. this error consider solved. i put the uses-permission out from application tag.